# Remove canonical URL error form WordPress web

Tags: php, wordpress, web-services

```
<link rel="canonical"
   href="http://www.brooklynsigns.com/retail-signs/stand-off-office-signs-new-york/"
   />
```

Google says to do it like this:

```
<link rel="canonical"
href="http://www.brooklynsigns.com/retail-signs/stand-off-office-signs-new-york"/>
```

What I want to do is that I URL in form like that `"/>`
instead of `/"/>`.

Answer (score 1):

Just change your [Permalinks settings](http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks) (`/wp-admin/options-permalink.php`) to use a **Custom Structure** and remove the last slash, putting the value **`/%postname%`**.

[image]

Comment: This *might* solve the OP issue, but what if he does not uses post names as permalink structure? Better approach is to use WP function `untrailingslashit( $url )` on the URL of the canonical link (via custom filter in the `functions.php` file or directly in `header.php`). Here are the details https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/untrailingslashit

Comment: @bodi0, yep, I thought of removing the action `rel_canonical` and adding a new one. But wouldn't it be a simple matter of adjusting ***any type*** of permalink structure and remove the trailing slash there?

Comment: Well, it depends, the OP can say that for sure (according his needs).